# convert a folder of mp4's to mp3's with ffmpeg?

Tags: bash

I have a folder mostly containing `mp4` videos. I want to extract the audio of those videos.

`for i in $(ls); do echo ffmpeg -i $i $i_mp3; done`

This command doesn't take any concern for the none mp4 files, and it seems to be adding line breaks in the `ls` command.

Comment: basic audio extraction with `ffmep` is `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn music.mp3` where `vn` is *no video* and `acodec` copy says use the same audio stream that's already in there; from [Github](https://gist.github.com/protrolium/e0dbd4bb0f1a396fcb55)

Comment: I suggest you also to add a `sed` command, in order to remove the `.mp4` extension on the filename, or your music filename would be for example `music.mp4.mp3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ls` command is superfluous: [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) should be just enough. I did not understand the *adding line breaks* part of your question though... I suppose you had problems with blank spaces in filenames.

I would personally use a variant of the following command:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn "$(basename "$f" .mp4).mp3"; done
```

The `basename` part is just to remove the `.mp4` suffix from *$f*. You can use some bash trickery instead, but I never remember the syntax.

Comment: Not only is it superfluous, it is also [a very bad idea to parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and doubly so for media files which often have strange names.

Comment: The bash trickery is: `"${f%.mp4}.mp3"` :)